# how to get address of end of data segment for calling brk

Tags: assembly, nasm

How can i get the address of the end of data segment? The assembly manuals i have read did not get deep enough.

I can't even get the address of beginning of data segment. The ds register contains zero

Answer (score 0):

In Nasm you can use `$`. From the manual:

> NASM supports two special tokens in expressions, allowing calculations to involve the current assembly position: the $ and $$ tokens. $ evaluates to the assembly position at the beginning of the line containing the expression; so you can code an infinite loop using JMP $. $$ evaluates to the beginning of the current section; so you can tell how far into the section you are by using ($-$$).

http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.5